# SSIS version checkout

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, business-intelligence

It's my very first post on this forum.

I have stuck with the Microsoft SSIS packages and I really don't knot how to beat it. I have mentioned SSIS package files and I tried to open it with Business Intelligence Development Studio on SQL Server 2005 - it resulted with an error which informs I need another version of it - I think it ment BIDS with SQL Server 2008.

As I have read further it appeared there is no free version of BIDS with SQL Server 2008.

If You have any idea how to handle it please let me know. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: can you show the error? I assume your are trying to open the project file, not the actual .dtsx package, right?

Comment: If you open the package with something like Notepad, the XML will tell you what version it targets. Look for `PackageFormatVersion` 2 is 2005, 3 is 2008, 6 is 2012

Comment: sure, when I open file 'Warehouse Packages.sln' with Programs -> MS SQL Server 2005 -> SQL Server BIDS (than MS Visual Studi 2005 opens) on Windows 7 Professional following error occurs with a popup window "The selected file is a solution file, but was created by a newer version of this application and cannot be opened."

Comment: I opened it with Notepad++ and it prints out "# Visual C# Express 2010" however I tried to open it with a trial version of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and following erros occurs 'C:\Users\Oskar\Desktop\Projects\dotnet_warehouse\dev\Warehouse Packages\Warehouse Packages\Warehouse Packages.dtproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.dtproj) is not supported by this version of the application. 
To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project.' so I guess some kind of version of BIDS is required to it? I have no clue at the time.

Comment: also - if it helps, following file extensions are included: (XSL Transform) / (integration service package) / (database file) / (dtproj file) /  (visual studio project user options file) / (Microsoft Visual Studio Solution) / (xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the SQL Server Express 2008 with Advanced Services version and it should give you a free version of the BIDS environment. The link is http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1842

Comment: So, it installs BIDS, but does not support SSIS? Thats weird.

Comment: So let me guys ensure myself... if project includes SSIS build in BIDS 2008 I won't open it with anything else? Further more... BIDS 2008 is only as a paid release?

Comment: Rajiv, I downloaded SQL Srv Express 2008 Adv Serv when I read following comparison of MS SQL Server products http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2008/08/11/sql-server-2008-express-now-available.aspx. However I can't open it either way.