# Deploy SSIS package to SQL Server 2008 SP3

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, msdeploy

I have a Production Database Server

> "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)      Sep 21 2011
>   22:45:45      Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation   Web Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)"

I create a SSIS package in Visual Studio 2008 BI
when I try to deploy my package to the database, 
I get below Error

**Storing or modifying packages in SQL Server requires the SSIS runtime and database to be the same version. Storing packages in earlier versions is not supported.**

Can this be considered as later version?

More Exception Details

Message

> Executed as user: DEV-03\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:23:16
>   PM  Error: 2012-12-11 16:23:16.92     Code: 0xC001700A     Source:
>   Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The
>   version number cannot be greater than current version number.  End
>   Error  Error: 2012-12-11 16:23:16.93     Code: 0xC0016020     Source: 
>   Description: Package migration from version 6 to version 3 failed with
>   error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The
>   version number cannot be greater than current version number.".  End
>   Error  Error: 2012-12-11 16:23:16.93     Code: 0xC0010018     Source: 
>   Description: Error loading value "6" from node
>   "DTS:Property".  End Error  Could not load package
>   "C:\userPath\SSIS\FullPackage.dtsx"
>   because of error 0xC0010014.  Description: The package failed to load
>   due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be
>   more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of
>   the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that
>   encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails. 
>   Source:   Started:  4:23:16 PM  Finished: 4:23:16 PM  Elapsed:  0.265
>   seconds.  The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.

Comment: What version of Sql Server is on the development machine with VS2008?

Comment: This was developed on SQL Server 20008 Developer edition

Comment: Which is it? Your comment says 2008 but your main post says `Visual Studio 2008 BI` "BI edition" only came out with SQL Server 2012. And as as @WilliamToddSalzman noted Version 6 **is** a 2012 package format while 3 is 2008. The error message says as much `Package migration from version 6 to version 3 failed`

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of different versions in play here @billinkc!  This is a good example of why you should strive to have a stable dev/prod environment and a source control system, so that you eliminate problems with versions.  When you are ready to move up to a new version, you should move them all at once.  Read below for even more version fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error, it looks like you are using VS2010 to develop a SQL Server 2012 package and then trying to deploy it to SQL Server 2008 R2.  From this comment on another question, you can see that version 6 in SSIS is Sql Server 2012  [SSIS version checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210130/ssis-version-checkout#comment13113761_10210130) (thanks @billinkc)  and version 10.50.2500.0 is Sql 2008 R2 SP1.  Are you sure that you are developing on the right machine and deploying to the right machine?

Comment: Yes I am Deploying to the right machine. Not sure, If I am developing on right machine(what is right machine to develop). I have to finally deploy to the above mentioned Database version. And you are right I had VS2010 then upgraded to VS2012 and VS2012 data tools. But he Package is created on Business Intelligence 2008 and still working on the save environment. I can run the package from BI2008

Comment: If you opened the package in VS2012 to make any changes, it would have automatically upgraded it.  You need to be careful of what version you change a package in to maintain the version that matches your server.

Comment: Well, is there any way for me to get this published now?

Comment: If you still have a package that works on the server (you mentioned a save environment), get a copy of vs2008 with bids and open the package, make the changes you need and deploy to the proper location,  Or retrieve it from your source control system and change it with vs2008 with bids and deploy it.  If you have already overwritten all of your sources, you will need to get vs2008 with bids and recreate the package from scratch. -- Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, solved it by just setting the version of the package to the old one, from:

```
VersionBuild: <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionBuild">87</DTS:Property>
VersionGUID: <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionGUID">{E7A9B363-E2DD-40CF-8126-70025D388B2E}</DTS:Property>
```

to:

```
VersionBuild: <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionBuild">72</DTS:Property>
VersionGUID: <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionGUID">{A82E6DDE-A5CD-4354-9953-31716F572E42}</DTS:Property>
```

works like a charm!

Comment: Only works if you did not modify any of the items that change function between releases.