# SSIS: The package format was migrated from version 6 to version 8. It must be saved to retain migration changes

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

Visual Studio Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5
SQL Server Data Tools 11.1.50730.0
SQL Server 2014 12.0.4213.0

I have converted a SQL 2005 SSIS to, what I would assume, would be the latest version of SSIS.

Using Visual Studio I have the deployed the project to a SQL2014 Server.
Each package within the project, when run, shows the following warning:

> The package format was migrated from version 6 to version 8. It must
>   be saved to retain migration changes.

Any ideas why this is and how to rectify?

Incidentally, within VS when I click on SSIS Packages --> Upgrade All Packages then none of the packages are displayed. Presumably because VS thinks they are all up to date?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. There's a small difference in the package format or possibly just the version number. That gets updated when you publish if going to a different version. (Could also be that your package targets 2012 and not 2014.)  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210130/ssis-version-checkout#comment13113761_10210130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had upgraded the package to a later version of SSIS - but **not the latest**.

**I downloaded the latest SSDT; upgraded the package and deployed. All was then OK.**

Before I performed the final upgrade I was getting the message:

> The package format was migrated from version 6 to version 8. It must be saved to retain migration changes.

This no longer appears - much happier!